# Google Drive desktop app prompts me to save photos from my flash drive every time I boot my PC

Tags: google-drive

I have the Google Drive desktop app installed to sync files between my PC (running Windows 10 Pro) and Google Drive, but every time I boot it up, I'm prompted to save photos from a flash drive I have plugged in. Even if I click "always" or "never", I'm prompted again the next time I reboot, as if it were a brand new drive. The drive is rather old, if that matters; it's a 1GB Lexar JumpDrive Sport dating from somewhere between 2001 and 2007. I don't have any photos on the drive, either, just a ReadyBoost cache, a text file, and some PDFs. It's only a minor nuisance but I thought I'd ask to see if there's any way to make my choice "stick".

Comment: Do you always use the same USB port?  Due to how USB devices work, a different port, would appear like a different device.  There are also third-party clients that provide you more control over. So if you are using the same port, and it still happens, use a different Google Drive client.

Comment: I haven't unplugged the drive in a while. I'm using the official client; you think a third party one would work better?

Comment: I think, if the official client is not doing what you want, you should use a different client.  Its more likely its simply a bug in the official client, or depending on the exact contents, a the client being to smart for its own good.  Either way a different client is the solution to avoid the prompt.